# How to convert a hexadecimal number to floating point binary by hand?

Tags: binary, floating-point, hex, ieee-754

How does one convert a hexadecimal number to its floating point binary equivalent (assuming that one exists, IEEE 754) by hand? 
I'd prefer simplified working rules (since this is not the main focus of my work).

Comment: Please can you give an example of input and output? There are various possible interpretations of your question.

Comment: Are we taking about using pencil & paper or just not using standard library function?